# Classify the input set into categories based on pre-defined rule set

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, decision-tree

I'm trying to solve a problem where there are 2 input files given,

**Input 1:**

A set of strings in the format. All the strings start with "A".

- A-B-C-D
- A-B-C-3
- A-X-Y-Z-4
- A-X-5
- A-X-P-Q-R
- A-X-P-Q-S
- A-M-9-P
- A-M-10-Q
- A-M-N-G-3
- A-V-B-H-3
- A-J-K-L-3-S-Y
- A-U-3-W-E

Here A,B,C,D,X,Y,Z,M.. (All alphabets are keywords and integers are placeholders)

**Input 2:**

A set of rules and names to each set of rules. Each rule set can have 1 or more rules. All the rule sets start with "A"

**Rule 1: (Name: Red)**

- A-X-^

**Rule 2: (Name: Blue)**

- A-X-P-Q-R
- A-X-P-Q-S

**Rule 3: (Name: Yellow)**

- A-X-P-Q-S
- A-X-P-Q-R

**Rule 4: (Name: Green)**

- A-M-$-P
- A-M-@-Q
- A-M-#-P

**Rule 5: (Name: Purple)**

- A-V-B-H-$
- A-J-K-L-$-S-Y
- A-U-$-W-E

Where alphabets are keywords, others (such as ^,$,@,#...) are placeholders. In a given rule set, if the placeholder is the same (like in rule 5), it means the place holder values have to be same, only then it belongs to this category. If they are different placeholders, then the values could be different.

**Problem Statement:**

Take input 1 (set of strings) and find which category the input belongs to, based on the rule sets from input 2. The output could be one or more categories. Also, the rules in the rule set may not appear in the input one after another.

There could be multiple other rules in between. For example, in rule 2, A-X-P-Q-R has to be followed by A-X-P-Q-S. It doesn't mean there cannot be others in between these two.

**Example:**

The input file could be

- A-X-P-Q-R
- A-Q-W
- A-Y-T-H
- A-X-P-Q-S

It still matches with rule 2 and belongs to "Blue"

**My Approach:**
I'm thinking of two approaches

- Using decision trees (or)
- Representing Input 1 as a graph and each of the individual rule sets in Input 2 as separate graphs and finding graph isomorphism.

Any thoughts?